# Finding a subset in a large dataset (>100) optimizing a parameter

Tags: r, optimization, subset, genetic-algorithm

I have a large matrix having this structure :

```
   A B C
A' 9 2 0
B' 2 8 0
C' 0 1 7
```

The diagonal terms represent the interaction of an individual (A) with his/her brother/sister (A'). Off diagonal elements represent the interaction of an individual with individuals not part of the family.

From a large set of individuals (say a few hundreds), I would like to find subsets (say 10) of individuals having minimal interactions with individuals not part of the family.

I was thinking of using a genetic algorithm (to optimize a parameter that I could calculate from the matrix) but could not find any algorithm that deals with subsets.

Is there a package in R (preferable) doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a name for this procedure? What field is it in? Package recommendations are off-topic. If you'd like help coding up your own algorithm, I'd suggest coming up with a **slightly** larger example and showing a desired result.

Comment: Or, could you set the diagonal elements to 0 and look for columns that have the lowest column sums? From what you've described, it doesn't seem like a complicated structure, and it's not clear why you'd want a genetic algorithm...

Comment: Assuming 10 individuals out of 120, there are 10^14 possibilities. So I thought it will be useful to use a genetic algorithm.

Comment: This tutorial https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756 , which I  have written, discusses how to select a few elements from many in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll outline binary genetic algorithm approach using `GA` package interface that you can use as baseline to create your own implementation. Because you have constraint that you want subset of specific length I will create mutation and crossover operators that will not ruin that specification (otherwise those operators will mostly create infeasible individuals).

**mutation**

```
mutation <- function(obj, parent){
  
  vec <- as.vector(obj@population[parent,])
  ind1 <- which(vec == 1)
  ind2 <- setdiff(seq_along(vec), ind1)
  
  ind1 <- sample(ind1, 1)
  ind2 <- sample(ind2, 1)
  vec[c(sample(ind1, 1), sample(ind2, 1))] <- c(0, 1) 
  
  vec
}
```

Mutation picks one position with 1 and one position with 0 and change their values to 0 and 1 respectively.

**crossover**

```
sizeCrossover <- function(size){
  
  function(obj, parents){
    
    vec1 <- obj@population[parents[1],] == 1
    vec2 <- obj@population[parents[2],] == 1
    
    c1 <- vec1 & vec2
    c1[sample(which(!c1), size - sum(c1))] <- 1
    
    c2 <- vec1 | vec2
    c2[sample(which(c2), sum(c2) - size)] <- 0
    
    list(children = rbind(c1, c2), fitness = c(NA, NA))
  }
}
```

Crossover is variation of arithmetic crossover. In case of & it needs to additionally change some 0 to 1 and in case of | it needs to additionally change some 1 to 0.

**initial population**

```
initialPopulation <- function(popSize, N, size){
  
  indices <- do.call(
    rbind,
    mapply(
      function(x, y) cbind(x, y), 
      seq_len(popSize),
      replicate(popSize, sample(seq_len(N), size), simplify = FALSE),
      SIMPLIFY = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  mm <- matrix(0, nrow = popSize, ncol = N)
  mm[indices] <- 1
  mm
}
```

If you create completely random initial population most (if not every) individuals will be infeasible. You need to create feasible initial population.

**fitness**

```
fitness <- function(vec, m, size){
  
  indices <- which(vec == 1)
  -sum(m[indices,indices])
}
```

`GA::ga` performas maximization hence the minus sign.

**random data and parameters**

```
N <- 200 # matrix dimensions
size <- 10 # subset length
popSize <- 100 # population size for genetic algorithm

m <- matrix(sample(0:10, N^2, TRUE), nrow = N)
diag(m) <- 0
```

**ga**

```
obj <- GA::ga(
  type = "binary",
  nBits = N,
  run = 500,
  maxiter = 10000,
  popSize = popSize,
  fitness = fitness,
  m = m,
  size = 10,
  suggestions = initialPopulation(popSize, N, size),
  mutation = mutation,
  crossover = sizeCrossover(size)
)

subset <- which(obj@solution[1,] == 1)
```

**note**

I'm using `sample` as modified in Advanced R:

```
sample <- function(x, size = NULL, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) {
  
  size <- size %||% length(x)
  x[sample.int(length(x), size, replace = replace, prob = prob)]
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will have a look this week-end !!!!

Comment: Thanks. When running I get a error in crossover(object, parents) : objet 'c1' cannot be found

Comment: I guess it is `c1 <- vec1 & vec2`

Comment: You're correct, dont know where that part disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the question is not fully specified so assume that the problem is as follows.  Let `v` be the vector of column sums of `m-diag(diag(m))` and let `k` be an input specifying the required number of individuals in the subset.  Then we wish to find the column names corresponding to the `k` smallest values in `v` or in terms of the language of integer linear programming we want to find the 0/1 vector `x` which minimizes `v'x` such that `sum(x) = k`.

We use the inputs and `v` defined in the Note at the end.

**1) sort** To minimize this we simply take the column names corresponding to the `k` smallest values of `v`.

```
names(head(sort(v), k))
## [1] "C" "A"
```

**2) knapsack** This can also be expressed as a knapsack problem.  `knapsack` maximizes so we use `max(v)-v` to get the effect of minimization.

```
library(adagio)

res.knap <- knapsack(rep(1, length(v)), max(v) - v, k)

names(v)[res.knap$indices]
## [1] "A" "C"
```

**3) linear programming** We can also use integer linear programming with the following solution.

```
library(lpSolve)

res.lp <- lp("min", v, t(rep(1, length(v))), "=", k, all.bin = TRUE)

res.lp
## Success: the objective function is 2 

names(v)[res.lp$solution == 1]
## [1] "A" "C"
```

**4) genalg** We use the rbga.bin genetic algorithm.

```
library(genalg)

set.seed(13)
f <- function(x) if (sum(x) == k) sum(x * v) else Inf
res.ga <- rbga.bin(size = length(v), evalFunc = f, popSize = 200, 
  mutation = .01, iters = 400)
cat(summary(res.ga))
## ...snip...
## GA Results
##   Best Solution : 1 0 1
```

### Note

The inputs are assumed to be:

```
k <- 2
m <- structure(c(9L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 7L), dim = c(3L, 
3L), dimnames = list(c("A'", "B'", "C'"), c("A", "B", "C")))

v <- colSums(m - diag(diag(m)))
```